# Почему выдаёт ошибку invalid character in identifier?

Tags: python

```
def R(x):
    if x <= 2:
        return 1
    elif x % 2 != 0:
        return R(x - 1) - x
    else:
        return R(x - 2) + g(x - 1) +2
def g(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 2
    elif x % 2 != 0:
        return R(x - 1) – 2 * R(x – 2)
    else:
        return 2 * R(x – 2) – 2 * g(x – 1)
print(R(96))
```

Comment: у вас написана длинная черта `–`, а не минус `-`. тут не сильно видно, но первая длиннее

Comment: В русском En dash вроде бы короткое тире.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас [тире](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013) вместо минуса.

```python
def R(x):
    if x <= 2:
        return 1
    elif x % 2 != 0:
        return R(x - 1) - x
    else:
        return R(x - 2) + g(x - 1) +2
def g(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 2
    elif x % 2 != 0:
        return R(x - 1) - 2 * R(x - 2)
    else:
        return 2 * R(x - 2) - 2 * g(x - 1)
print(R(96))
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.